# Apline Linux How to force static nameserver if inet dhcp

Tags: dns, alpine-linux

On Alpine Linux
/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

in the /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

When I reboot machine I will get new DNS server IP from DHCP server

**Question**:
how to force static nameserver in the /etc/resolv.conf so it points to 1.1.1.1 instead of nameserver from DHCP?

Answer (score 1):

set `RESOLV_CONF="no"` in  `/etc/udhcpc/udhcpc.conf`. See https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Udhcpc

Answer (score 1):

Harry's answer is a better approach.

But you can also just make resolv.conf immutable:
`chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`